# sp_send_dbmail Stored Procedure Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm nearing completion of a query that is desigend to send daily email updates to people who commit an error when processing an order through a specific software. The data is being pulled from tables within a CTE. The query runs and the emails send if I have the @ExcelOutput variable set to the follwing:

`SET @ExcelOutput = ('SELECT [Rep Name], [Temp Rep Number], [Error Code], [Account Number], [Report Date] FROM ##TempEmailTest')`

However, if I add a where clause, which I need to add for the logic to work correctly, the query throws the following error:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

```
SET @ExcelOutput = ('SELECT [Rep Name], [Temp Rep Number], [Error Code], [Account Number], [Report Date] FROM ##TempEmailTest WHERE [Temp Rep Number] >= @Loop')
```

Here's the full query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempEmailTest') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE ##TempEmailTest
END

USE MyDataBase
GO

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 
    a.[Temp Rep Number],
    a.[Rep Name],
    a.[Error Code],
    a.[Account Number],
    a.[Report Date],
    a.[Test Email]

FROM
(SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY org.[Rep Name]) AS [Temp Rep Number],
    org.[Rep Name],
    tab.[Error Code],
    tab.[Account Number],
    tab.[Report Date],
    'test@test.com' AS [Test Email]

FROM tbl_mytable org
INNER JOIN tbl_mytable1 tab ON org.[Rep Name] = tab.[Rep Name]

WHERE tab.[Total Errors] <> 0
AND tab.[Report Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),1)) AS a) 

SELECT
    [Temp Rep Number], 
    [Rep Name],
    [Error Code],
    [Account Number],
    [Report Date],
    [Test Email]

INTO ##TempEmailTest
FROM CTE

DECLARE @Loop int
SET @Loop = 1

DECLARE @LoopEnd int
SET @LoopEnd = (SELECT MAX([Temp Rep Number]) AS [Temp Row Number] FROM ##TempEmailTest) 

WHILE @Loop <= @LoopEnd
BEGIN 

DECLARE @TempRepNumber int
DECLARE @RepName nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @RepEmail nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @AccountNumber varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ErrorCode varchar(Max)
DECLARE @ExcelOutput varchar(2048)


SELECT
    @TempRepNumber = [Temp Rep Number],
    @RepName = [Rep Name],
    @Accountnumber = [Account Number],  
    @ErrorCode = [Error Code]
FROM ##TempEmailTest
WHERE @Loop = [Temp Rep Number]

SET @RepEmail =  (SELECT 
                 Email.[Test Email]
                 FROM
                 (SELECT 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Test Email]) AS [Email Row],
                 [Test Email] 
                 FROM ##TempEmailTest
                 WHERE [Temp Rep Number] = @Loop) AS Email
                 WHERE Email.[Email Row] = 1)   


SET @ExcelOutput = ('SELECT [Rep Name], [Temp Rep Number], [Error Code], [Account Number], [Report Date] FROM ##TempEmailTest WHERE [Temp Rep Number] = @Loop')

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'test_profile',
@recipients = @RepEmail,
@from_address = 'Test@test1.com',
@subject = 'test',
@body = 'test',
@query = @ExcelOutput,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv',
@query_result_separator=',', --enforce csv
@query_result_no_padding=1, --trim
@query_result_width=32767  --stop wordwrap

SET @Loop = @Loop + 1

END
```

Comment: It's a completely useless error right? You will find more information if your run SQL Profiler and see what it's doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Attempted to run with a trace and it's not even populating results within SQL Profiler.

Comment: Can you capture the functioning one in Profiler without the WHERE clause? If you can't then you need to tweak profiler.

Comment: If you just want to solve it you could delete the records from `##TempEmailTest` beforehand - then you don't need a WHERE. You could also feed the loop with DISTINCT - I beleive that's what you're trying to do. Lastly - does the query work if you take the email bit out?

Comment: To be clear, I'm trying to have the excel output sent to individual people. The [TempRepNumber] will read a row to send the selected data to a particular people. The loop should be reading the next [TempRepNumber] row in line, send the email with the .csv output and then restart the loop until finished.

Comment: Okay - I've got it to the point where it'll send the email and delete each row from the previous loop. The only issue now is that when the email is sent all of the existing data is sent in the email. Once the loop reaches the very end the last email sent has only one person's data. To clarify, I only want each .csv file to contain the data for the particular [Temp Rep Number] field.

Comment: Problem solved! I messed with the @ExcelOutput query and got it to read:

WHERE [Temp Rep Number] = (SELECT MIN([Temp Rep Number]) FROM ##TempEmailTest) and it's working is intended :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic723716-338-1.aspx

```
SET @ExcelOutput = 'SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT [Rep Name], [Temp Rep Number], [Error Code], [Account Number], [Report Date] FROM ##TempEmailTest WHERE [Temp Rep Number]  >'  + cast(@Loop as varchar(3))
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Just attempted it and I'm still getting the same error:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Again, if I take out the WHERE clause the query runs and sends the emails, it just doesn't filter the results like I need them to do with the set declared variable of @Loop.

Comment: firstly can you send email just by testing?

Comment: i think the issue here is the @loop variable.. should be passed as parameter

Comment: Yes, the email function is working correctly. It's right when I attempt that WHERE clause when the query doesn't work any longer.

Comment: Would mind providing quick sample code of what that would look like? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I apologize for the late response - I'm getting the same cryptic error when I attempt your solution.

Comment: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

I'm unable to decipher what this error is from any resources online...